# Laravel Live Messaging System

Tags: messaging, laravel-5.4

Heey everyone! I was doing a project using Laravel, and now I get to the point to make a private one-to-one chat. So far I made chat using Database, which requires reloadings and etc. But I want to enhance it, so that is was really good, with stuff like: writing, automatic receiving and sending (without reloading page).

What can you offer and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax or websocket.

In ajax, you can simply fetch new messages and update the DOM by using setInterval.

```
function start() {
    $start = setInterval(function() {
        fetch_chat_messages();    
    }, 3000);
}
start();
```

The only disadvantage here is that the DOM keeps on refreshing.

While in Websocket, realtime communication will be possible. I will recommend you to use http://socket.io/.

Goodluck!

Comment: Welcome @КенжебаевСагынбек